# multiple upload dynamic file

Tags: php, file-upload

My problem is when the list input file is dynamic, so here is the code :

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    $syarat = array('2','3','4','7');
    $path = "./uploadtest/";
    $jmlsyarat = count($syarat);
        for($y = 0; $y<$jmlsyarat; $y++) {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file){
                $namafile = $syarat[$y].".jpg";
                $tmpfile = $file['tmp_name'];
                $kefile = $path.$namafile;
                move_uploaded_file($tmpfile,$kefile);
            }
        }
}
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/uploadtest.php">
<input type="file" name="2" />
<input type="file" name="3" />
<input type="file" name="4" />
<input type="file" name="7" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Can it be done with dynamic handler that I create at above?
Thank you in advance

Comment: what's the problem that you are facing exactly?

Comment: @Federkun it is not working for multiple upload. It ended up in upload the last input file.

Comment: More correctly, you correctly move all the uploaded file to `2.jpg`. On the second iteration of that outer `for` loop you already moved all the files (using the same filename, so overriding them, showing just the last one in the end).

Comment: @Federkun so you mean that I should move foreach above the for? I need the file name to be the name input file. Not the uploaded file name...

Comment: You don't need that `for` loop at all. `foreach ($_FILES as $y => $file){` -- in this case `$y` should contains '2','3','4', or '7'.

Comment: @Federkun thank you. I will do it in few seconds. I am om the road now

Comment: @Federkun do you mean that I do not need $syarat at all? And how the var $y come from?

Comment: `$y` is the name of the `input` html tag. as such you don't really need `jmlsyarat`.

Comment: @Federkun thx man... that work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

here is the work code (thx to @Federkun) :

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_FILES)){

        $path = "./uploadtest/";

                foreach ($_FILES as $y => $file){
                    $namafile = $y.".jpg";
                    $tmpfile = $file['tmp_name'];
                    $kefile = $path.$namafile;
                    move_uploaded_file($tmpfile,$kefile);
                }

    }
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/uploadtest.php">
<input type="file" name="2" />
<input type="file" name="3" />
<input type="file" name="4" />
<input type="file" name="7" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

That code work perfectly!